# Delete item from nested object array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I'm working with AngularJS and have an object array like that in my controller :

```
$scope.folderList = [{
    name: 'root',
    path: 'uploads/',
    subs: [{
        name: 'pictures',
        path: 'uploads/pictures',
        subs: [{
            ...
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'videos',
        path: 'uploads/videos',
        subs: [{
            ...
        }]
    }]
}];
```

For this nested array, I have 2 directives set them up in a nested UL LI list with ng-repeat.

Now I have my nested list of folders, and I want to trigger a function to delete the selected folder.

So I trigger my function to delete with "folder" in parameter, for example, if I trigger the "delete" function on the pictures folder, the folder parameter will be like that :

```
folder = {
    name: 'pictures',
    path: 'uploads/pictures',
    subs: [{ ... }]
}
```

And I want to delete this object from the nested array.

With a 1 level object array, I use this :

```
var index = $scope.folderList.indexOf(folder);
delete $scope.folderList.splice(index, 1);
```

But it (obviously) doesn't work on a nested array !

How can I easily delete an entry from a nested array on JavaScript (or AngularJS ?)

I've heard that underscore.js was made for this, but I never used it, and after seeing their  documentation I wasn't able to find the proper function to do this !

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You will need to write a recursive function over `subs` for this. You may also need to think how you'll perform your compare if the search parameter `folder` is an identical _Object_ but not the same reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

I could use the "path" to get where I want to be. Then i'll have several index of each parent folders ? (For example, to go on the "pictures" folder, I'll have [0, 0]). But, I don't think I can do : "delete $scope.folderList.splice([0, 0], 1);" ? How can, if I have all indexes to go to the right folder, delete the right folder from those indexes ? Can I use splice ? Or is there another function for that ?

Comment: You still use splice, but you use the correct `this` to call it on `var cd = $scope.folderList; cd = cd[0]; cd.splice(0, 1);`

Comment: Thanks ! It worked, and was easier than I thought and quite obvious for the splice, now that I saw it !